# How to integrate Adobe Creative SDK Feather Editor in Ionic/Cordova

Tags: angularjs, cordova, ionic-framework, aviary, adobecreativesdk

I am creating a mobile hybrid app with the Ionic framework, and I'm trying to integrate the Feather Editor. My best scenario would be that a Cordova plugin was available, since the Adobe Creative Web SDK is not optimized for mobile, but the Android and iOS SDKs are.

There are some legacy plugins, some of which are only for iOS, and the following one, which seems to be outdated, since the Feather Editor wouldn't launch:

https://github.com/m1is/AviaryCordovaPlugin

I also tried the following angular directive:

https://github.com/m00s/angular-aviary

This directive works for web, but on mobile it is not working properly, I guess because of the fact that the web SDK is not optimized for mobile. What happens is that the Feather Editor launches but it takes too much space, not fitting into the mobile screen. Plus, the tools are not showing, and a loading icon is shown forever.

So I guess that the right path would be to create a new Cordova plugin that works with the latest Cordova and Adobe Creative Android/iOS SDKs.

Has anyone tried a different approach?

Comment: Have you got any luck?

Comment: Yeah, I went for the hard approach, I developed my own Cordova plugin :)

https://github.com/jguix/Cordova-FeatherEditor

Answer (score 2):

The Creative SDK team recently collaborated with PhoneGap to release plugins that are compatible with PhoneGap, Cordova, and Ionic.

Among them are the new [Image Editor UI PhoneGap plugin](https://github.com/CreativeSDK/phonegap-plugin-csdk-image-editor) and [template](https://github.com/CreativeSDK/phonegap-template-csdk-image-editor).

[More details are on the Creative SDK blog](https://blog.creativesdk.com/2016/09/phonegap-plugin-roundup/).

You can get a quick overview of everything on offer on [the Creative SDK GitHub page's Plugins section](https://creativesdk.github.io/#plugins).

Answer (score 1):

I developed this Cordova plugin:

https://github.com/jguix/Cordova-FeatherEditor

It currently supports Android.